# how to iplement name route instead id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need url like,

> localhost:3000/newyork

instead,

> localhost:3000/19

Comment: use friendly_id gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gem file write

```
 gem "friendly_id"
```

After writing the gem in gemfile run bundle install

Create a migration to add slugs column in the model

```
 rails g migration AddSlugToCity

 add_column :cities, :slug, :string
 add_index :cities, :slug, unique: true
```

In your controller write

```
  @city = City.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

In your city module use friendly id

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `get '/:city_name' => 'city#city_method', as: 'city'`

use it like `<%= link_to @city.name, city_path(city_name: @city.name) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to specify `param` in your routes:

```
resources :cities, param: :name
```

Also, Rails uses `to_param` method defined on Models, which should return what param are you looking for – you need to define that on City too:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def to_param; name; end
  # ...
end
```

Then, when you generate a route you can pass object directly to `city_path`:

```
link_to @city.name, city_path(@city)
```

and last, but not least, adjust your controller to `find_by` that `name`, not id:

```
@city = City.find_by! name: params[:name]
```

Or, for out-of-the-box solution try some existing gems like `friendly_id`!